# How do I SKIP the already iterated rows but read the next rows that are not being iterated?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am trying to loop through a collection i.e. but it should iterate only according to the pagination value.

See, I have this:

```
var SkipCount= 0;
var TakeCount= 50;

var list= db.tblCollection.where(r => r.Id > 1).orderby(r=> r.Id).Take(Take).Skip(SkipCount);

var totalTableRecords= list.count(); // 200 records in my case
var counter= 0;
```

now the outer loop shall be running until it reaches the total value of totalTableRecords-1.
And for inner loop for each iteration of outer loop it shall check only take the specified number of records.

```
for( ;counter < totalTableRecords; )
{
     foreach(var l in list)
     {
          //Do some coding here
          
          counter= counter + 1;
          
     }
          SkipCount= TakeCount;
          TakeCount= TakeCount+ 50;
          
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that in 1st run of outer loop the inner loop shall do some execution based on the trimmed i.e. `1st 50` records. Then, in the second run we do need to skip the already executed `50` records in 1st run and shall be the next `50` records. Then in the third loop it shall ignore the already read `100` records in `1st` and `2nd` run `(50+50)` and next `50` records until the counter of outer loop hits the condition.

I tried this but it keep on running till the limit i.e. `200` while the actual work is done is only `4` iterations.

How do I solve this?

Comment: If you're going to process all records, there is no need for total number of records, just fetch 50 next records in each outer iteration until there are no more records to fetch. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling the code you posted is not quite the same as what you've been testing. Changing `SkipCount` and `TakeCount` inside the inner loop (for every item you iterate through) seems wrong.

I'll rewrite a bit, but overall: just keep `TakeCount` (page size) constant and increase `SkipCount` (page number):

```
pageNum = 0; // Instead of SkipCount
pageSize = 50; // Instead of TakeCount
List<SomeType> page;

do
{
    page = db.tblCollection.Where(r => r.Id > 1)
        .OrderBy(r => r.Id)
        .Skip(pageNum * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();

     foreach (var l in page)
     {
          //Do some coding here
     }

     pageNum++;
} while (page.Count > 0);
```

Comment: hi, thanks but page.count > 0; wouldn't it be infinite because we ain't doing anything to compute the count?

Comment: also, i think this piece would iterate and not stop

Comment: @afaaqadabookick no, it shouldn't. If you have 200 records, then when `pageNum` is 4, you'll get 0 items in the list because you skip `4 * 50 = 200` and take `50`. But there are no records after the 200 you skip, so you actually "take" 0.

Comment: ahhhhhh ok ok. great, so if I havea ny number of rows, lets say 500, it would work for that too? right?

Comment: @afaaqadabookick yep. You can try out an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/i7EMcu just change the size of the `sourceCollection` and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you are looking for something like the code below. It will iterate over 200 items in 4 batches.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MyDataSource()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This will only be printed once");

    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}

[Test]
public void SkipTest()
{
    var skipCount = 0;
    const int takeCount = 50;

    for (;;)
    {
        var currentList = MyDataSource().Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount).ToArray();
        if (!currentList.Any())
        {
            return;                        
        }
        
        foreach (var currentVal in currentList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentVal);
        }
        skipCount += takeCount;
    }
}
```